# Internet Explorer not opening index.html

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have a little problem with IExplorer. The problem is that in the home of the website (lets suppose it is www.example.com) I have a little index.html file that contains the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.example.com/myredrection/" />
  </head>
</html>
```

The problem is that while Firefox and Chrome automatically load the index.html file and get redirected to the right folder (myredirection in the example), IExplorer is not doing this. It does not automatically open the index.html when I point it to example.com, thus reporting a "Page can't be displayed" error.

Am I missing something?

Comment: what is your web server? IIS?

Comment: @Roman: nope, it's apache

Comment: I see,..I'm not familiar with Apache but did you check how URL redirection and Default documents are being set in your web server?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar case. Issue was caused by empty (or missed) Content-Type header in the server response. looks like IE relies on that header to render and show the response. 
So, suggestion is to check web server config to make sure it is able to fill Content-Type. In case of Apache HTTPD start point to check: mime.type